# Iterate through a list of dates with a known interval and create list with inverse dates in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a list of dates/times with a known interval of 10 minutes to create a list of all inverse times. I need to block off calendar times that are not available; but i only know what calendar times are available to start. My list of available slots needs to populate a calendar by blocking off all of the time that the user is not available. Each of the available appointments from my endpoint is a 10 minute interval.

Input Data Set:

```
6/7/19 - 8:00
6/7/19 - 8:20
6/7/19 - 9:30
6/7/19 - 10:10
6/7/19 - 11:20
```

With the known 10 minute interval, this means 8:00 - 8:10 is available, and should not be in my resulting list. I also block from day start 00:00 until first opening, and from last appointment, until end of day.

Expected Output:

```
6/7/19 - 0:00,8:00 
6/7/19 - 8:10,8:20
6/7/19 - 8:30,9:30
6/7/19 - 9:40,10:10
6/7/19 - 10:20,11:20
6/7/19 - 11:30,24:59
```

My current code:

```
        '// Setup some test data 
        Dim DateList As New List(Of DateTime)
        DateList.Add(New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0))
        DateList.Add(New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 8, 20, 0))
        DateList.Add(New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 9, 30, 0))
        DateList.Add(New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 10, 10, 0))
        DateList.Add(New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 11, 20, 0))

        Dim DateTemplate As New List(Of Tuple(Of DateTime, DateTime))
        '// Calculate starting offset
        DateTemplate.Add(Tuple.Create(New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0), DateList.First.AddMinutes(0)))
        '// Loop through items
        For idx = 0 To (DateList.Count - 2)
            DateTemplate.Add(Tuple.Create(DateList(idx).AddMinutes(10), DateList(idx + 1).AddMinutes(0)))
        Next
        '// Calculate ending offset
        DateTemplate.Add(Tuple.Create(DateList.Last.AddMinutes(10), New DateTime(2019, 6, 7, 23, 59, 0)))

        For Each i In DateTemplate '// Show to console to debug
            Console.WriteLine(i.Item1.ToString & " - " & i.Item2.ToString)
        Next
```

Comment: It looks like your code produces the expected output.

Comment: @jimi yes it does, my question was more to inquire if there is a more elegant way, or simpler way of performing this type of calculating. In my above example it would fail under many situation (no appointments open) (only 1 appointment open).

Comment: These conditions are known to you only (and you didn't mention these conditions in your question). You need to test your code under different situations. That's what Unit Tests are about. Build a test project. You can, eventually, post yur code (with a good description of these specific functionalities) on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split your day up in 10 minute intervals you know that there will be 144 slots (`60 minutes / 10 intervals * 24 hours`). With that being said, the way that I would tackle this problem would be to create a Dictionary where the key would represent the Date and the value would be a String array.

The values in the String array would be an Empty string to represent an open time slot or populated to represent an existing appointment.

You could then calculate the Date and Time by getting the outer Dictionary's key and the time by multiplying the index of the String in relation to the array by 10.

Take a look at this example:

```
Dim DateTemplate As New Dictionary(Of Date, String())
For Each existingAppointment As DateTime In DateList
    If Not DateTemplate.ContainsKey(existingAppointment.Date) Then
        DateTemplate.Add(existingAppointment.Date, Enumerable.Range(1, 144).Select(function(i) String.Empty).ToArray())
    End If
    DateTemplate(existingAppointment.Date)(existingAppointment.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes \ 10) = "Apointment Booked"
Next
```

Live Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FygG54